# React Naitve Redux getState Undefined

Tags: react-native, react-redux, redux-persist

I am trying to Firebase Phone Authentication with React-redux. but i am getting getState undefined in Action file.

i am getting "confirmResult.confirm is undefined"

```
 Action.Js
 const onCodeDispatched = (code) => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        console.log(getState())
        getState().auth.confirmResult.confirm(code)
        .then(user => onLoginSuccess(dispatch, user))
        .catch(error => onCodeConfirmError(dispatch, error));
    }    
}

App.js
import React from 'react'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import {createStore, applyMiddleware, compose} from 'redux'
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'

import reducers from '../reducers'
import App from './App'

import {persistStore} from 'redux-persist'
import {PersistGate} from 'redux-persist/es/integration/react'

const middleware = [thunkMiddleware]
const store = compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware))(createStore)(reducers)
console.log(store)
let persistor = persistStore(store)

class Root extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
          <App />
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}

export default Root
```

i am new in react-redux it is very confusing me i already read many articles i already spent many days finding the error can you please give me some idea why getState is returning Undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Try to split how are you constructing the store. You can begin creating just a simple instance of store, like this:

```
const store = createStore(reducers, yourInitialState)
```

Then print the store and see what happened. If everything is okay, try to use `compose`, `applyMiddleware`, and `thunk` like that:

```
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk),
    DevTools.instrument() // this is a really helpful instrument
  )
)
```

If you have doubts just ask or follow the official doc from [Redux website](https://redux.js.org/api/compose)

Comment: thanks for reply i tested as you said. i got conclusion that The confirmResult is going into redux and being modified/serialized (basically its removing the function). how can i stop this please help i am new to redux

Comment: hey man, can you please explain better what is happening? I think you're talking about [that](https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state#can-i-put-functions-promises-or-other-non-serializable-items-in-my-store-state), you shouldn't put methods in the redux state